# Oracle 12c Pluggable Database in Restricted Mode

Tags: database, oracle12c, pluggable

We created Container Database but when we try to create PDB it gets created in Restricted Mode.

```
SQL> SELECT v.name, v.open_mode, v.restricted, d.status
FROM v$pdbs v, dba_pdbs d WHERE v.guid = d.guid ORDER BY v.create_scn; 

NAME         OPEN_MODE   RES STATUS 
=======================================================================
PDB$SEED      READ ONLY  NO  NORMAL
NMPDBTST      READ WRITE YES NORMAL
```

Following is the extract from  dba_registry;

```
SQL>  select comp_id||'|'||comp_name||'|'||version||'|'||status||'|'||procedure from dba_registry;
COMP_ID||'|'||COMP_NAME||'|'||VERSION||'|'||STATUS||'|'||PROCEDURE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------
DV|Oracle Database Vault|12.1.0.2.0|VALID|VALIDATE_DV
APEX|Oracle Application Express|4.2.5.00.08|VALID|VALIDATE_APEX
OLS|Oracle Label Security|12.1.0.2.0|VALID|VALIDATE_OLS
SDO|Spatial|12.1.0.2.0|VALID|VALIDATE_SDO
ORDIM|Oracle Multimedia|12.1.0.2.0|VALID|VALIDATE_ORDIM
CONTEXT|Oracle Text|12.1.0.2.0|VALID|VALIDATE_CONTEXT
OWM|Oracle Workspace Manager|12.1.0.2.0|VALID|VALIDATE_OWM
XDB|Oracle XML Database|12.1.0.2.0|VALID|DBMS_REGXDB.VALIDATEXDB
CATALOG|Oracle Database Catalog       Views|12.1.0.2.0|VALID|DBMS_REGISTRY_SYS.VALIDATE_CATALOG
CATPROC|Oracle Database Packages and Types|12.1.0.2.0|VALID|DBMS_REGISTRY_SYS.VALIDATE_CATPROC
JAVAVM|JServer JAVA Virtual Machine|12.1.0.2.0|VALID|INITJVMAUX.VALIDATE_JAVAVM
XML|Oracle XDK|12.1.0.2.0|VALID|XMLVALIDATE
CATJAVA|Oracle Database Java Packages|12.1.0.2.0|VALID|DBMS_REGISTRY_SYS.VALIDATE_CATJAVA
APS|OLAP Analytic Workspace|12.1.0.2.0|VALID|APS_VALIDATE
XOQ|Oracle OLAP API|12.1.0.2.0|VALID|XOQ_VALIDATE
RAC|Oracle Real Application Clusters|12.1.0.2.0|OPTION OFF|DBMS_CLUSTDB.VALIDATE
```

Following is the output from pdb_plug_in_violations

```
SQL> select name||'|'||message||'|'||action||'|'||type||'|'||status from     pdb_plug_in_violations where type ='ERROR';
**NAME||'|'||MESSAGE||'|'||ACTION||'|'||TYPE||'|'||STATUS**
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PDB$SEED|Database option CATJAVA mismatch: PDB installed version . CDB installed version 12.1.0.2.0.|Fix the database option in the PDB or the CDB|ERROR|PENDING
PDB$SEED|Database option ORDIM mismatch: PDB installed version . CDB installed version 12.1.0.2.0.|Fix the database option in the PDB or the CDB|ERROR|PENDING
NMPDBTST|Database option CATJAVA mismatch: PDB installed version . CDB installed version 12.1.0.2.0.|Fix the database option in the PDB or the CDB|ERROR|PENDING
NMPDBTST|Database option ORDIM mismatch: PDB installed version . CDB installed version 12.1.0.2.0.|Fix the database option in the PDB or the CDB|ERROR|PENDING
```

Can somebody suggest me what the mistake we are doing while creating CDB/PDB.

Thanks in anticipation.

Regards,
Rohit Gulati

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, This has been resolved.

On analyzing all logs we came to know that java_pool_size was not sufficient and because of this JVM was not getting installed properly.
Once we increased the java_pool_size to 150 MB, we were able to create pluggable database.

Regards,
Rohit